# Install Ubuntu in Hyper-V Server 2012

Tags: windows, ubuntu, hyper-v

i just try to install Hyper-V Server 2012 Native version.There is no GUI inside on Hyper-V native version

I want to running ubuntu inside Hyper-V Server.

Any documentation how to do it ? or documentation how to use Hyper-V Server Native version ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hyper-V server is basically just a core WIndows server - welcome to the documentation.

PowerShell would work. PowerShell has cmdlets for managing Hyper-V.

RSAT - Rmote Server Administration Tools - also works. Administrate it from another server or a windows 8 machine.

Comment: Any documentation for step by step using command line to deploy ubuntu insde hyper-v server ? on official website documentation to less :(

Comment: Nope, I dont do linux at all. I have a windows network, so - I have all the UI I need. I do not think you will get happy without a wind8 machine to run a local Hyper-V (which you can use to install ubuntu, then copy the machine over).